# How to implement long-running tasks in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, progress, long-running-processes

I am implementing a ASP.Net 4.0 Application in which on button click 1000 around rules will be evaluated.It is taking 10 minutes to evaluate all rules.

**How to show progress in web page.**

**That should allow the user to do other tasks like cancellation etc.**

Once all rules are evaluated data in the page needs to be updated and a message should be shown.

**How can i implement this in ASP.Net?**

Comment: Please ask a single, specific question and show us the code you have.

Comment: This is actually quite difficult. The problem is that if you run the 10m request through asp.net and IIS, it can be terminated at any time once the HTTP request that spawns it finishes. So you need to make a service on the server separate from asp.net, and have it communicate with the main web server application somehow.

Comment: Also, it is a bad idea to do this in an ASP.NET page. Have the page queue the request to a service that will run the request. Be certain that the service does not perform the 10 minute task twice in case the user presses F5. The progress bar can then monitor the progress of the service.

Comment: There's many way to approach, ajax request/s,Multithreading,Service on server it will depend which type needs you have.In example you can make one single ajax call which call a page which take care to execute all the rules validation in multithreading (if is possibile),connect to a server service and get response from it and so on.....may u give us more info? Is evalutaion done in a particular order or could be swithced into several tasks/threads so this will reduce total working time ?More you say us more we can help you

Comment: Thanks for replying. All the rules need to be evaluated in particular order. But, at any time user should be able to cancel rule evaluation process. When rule evaluation is completed/ aborted some other data in the same page needs to be updated with evaluation rule result.

Comment: so it configured as for my last answer in this page.Ajax solution.Take a look in my next response.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement this using signalr framework from MS. We do it for example for installation procedure in our product. Also a long running process. Since product is open source, you can examine the implementation at:

https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-community/blob/master/src/Presentation/FrontEnd/StoreWebApp/Areas/VirtoAdmin/Views/Install/Index.cshtml

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In this case my personal advice is to use simple ajax request

In example you may call a first load call where it will take care to initialize task

Save in session a values to this task in example fantasy name Session("taksprogress")="0"
and you will update your progress bar with this value

Second one start a timer on page which check each five second and report the update cheking only your actual status of session("taskprogress").

When it will return a value defined by you at that point you will be show your message to client side.

It will help you more and it really simple to achive.
Take care to remember that if you will use an ashx file you must enable right permission to accesso in read/write mode to session.
There are many other way to do it with classes, json response which include text messages and so on :)
I hope that can help you to choose the right way to choose.

Hi Shiva, as per your last comment is better choose ajax in this case assume this situation :

1. button "START" to make ajax call to .aspx/ashx(i preferr it) which takes care to run long task
2. button "CANCEL" which will be used to make another ajax call to stop the long task
3. progress bar which will be updated with some info
4. At this point you need to make some javascript function to handle your need to update progress bar and so on.

In example you will have one call to start the task on to stop the taks one to retrive status you can assume that in your ashx file you can pass many parameters as per your need in example

http://domain.com/ajax/longtask.ashx?task=start

http://domain.com/ajax/longtask.ashx?task=update

http://domain.com/ajax/longtask.ashx?task=cancel

in this case you can use one single ajax call to do all the stuff and facing the task called you may use a switch case in javascript to elaborate.

You have also to create one single function to enable timer to call services at defined interval like 2 second 1 second 5 second

When task will run (task=start) it will update session with new values and with update you only retrieve this data from session too

In case of task cancel you will set a flag in session to say to your procedure to exit and return the result which via ajax in json format

that's all

checking your logic, construct and classes to be sure that you can implement this logi in simple manner.You can also create a custom class in example MonitoringLongTask which expose several information and so each time you need to communicate/retreve you only need to update "MonitoringLongTask" class properties.

I hope it can help you

UPDATE ON YOUR LAST COMMENT :

> Not sure to understand Siva, did you means that you post some data from a form and then evaluation could run?? no prob same stuff or better 2 different ajax call nothing else.First ajax call send data to database and elaborate it and return ok or failed within the success function into ajax call call your second fucntion which start the task to bind both calls you may create a custom token to pass to the first response wich will be added to second call in example : firt call http://domain.com/ajax/lng.ashx?task=store&param1=0&param2=1 etc etc it will return a simple token in example a guid or id taken from database for this particular task and pass it as parameter in 2 call like http://domain.com/ajax/lng.ashx?task=start&uid=yourtoken

Comment: Thanks. Here one more problem is data in the page needs to be saved to database and then only rule evaluation should start. If it is Ajax call how can i achieve this?

Comment: Checking update on response :)